# In-App Messaging crashes in firebase crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I added new feature in app for show in-app Messaging campaign. but when the splash is loading at that time its show campaign and splash screen will be disappear with-in few sec. so application throws an crashes.

Here is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:894)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamWindowManager.show(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay$5.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.loadNullableImage(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.inflateBinding(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.access$400(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**So how to prevent for stop showing in-app messaging campaign for specific activity?**

Comment: I faced the same but it still in queue

Comment: @MD have you find any listner for in-app message display. or any method which remove dialog programmatically.?

Comment: it is context problem with Dialog .please check...

Comment: @GautamKushwaha yes, that i know man, but its gives by an firebase in app messanging

Answer (score 2):

After some research I solved my issue with my custom firebase event.

Just log your custom firebase event in your screen where you want your campaign dialog.
and schedule your campaign with your custom event.

That's it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not always work. For example, if you have an image in your campaign. If may get loaded and shown anytime and it causes a similar crash. (Even with the latest firebase.inappmessaging.display library)